# Mock destructed import with Jest?

Tags: jestjs

I'm trying to mock a destructed import with Jest.

In the component is the destructed import:

```
import { getSomething } from 'utils/paymentUtils';
```

In the test:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Component from 'components/Component';
import * as utils from 'utils/paymentUtils';

jest.mock('utils');

describe('Something', () => {
  let wrapper;    
  utils.getSomething.mockImplementation(() => 'Blah');
```

The error I'm getting is:

> Cannot find module 'utils' from 'Component.spec.js'

Comment: Is your component in the same directory of your test ?

Comment: try mocking the same path: `jest.mock('utils/paymentUtils')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to mock the module itself, in this case `utils/paymentUtils`